# Question on Murabaha (selling the product before the end of the contract period)

Tags: finance, banking

Assalamu alaikum All,

In a Murabaha, can the Buyer/Agent of the product, who promises to buy the product from the Seller at a later point in time, sell the product to his customer (with the Seller's permission) before the end of the Murabaha contract?

For instance, the Buyer/Agent wants to buy some scarves to resell to its customers. As it needs funding, the Buyer/Agent approaches the Seller and asks if the Seller can purchase the scarves with a promise that the Buyer/Agent will purchase the same scarves from the Seller some time later at an agreed higher price. Before the end of the Murabaha contract, the Buyer/Agent sells the scarves to its customers with permission from the Seller. And at the end of the Murabaha contract, the Buyer/Agent pays the Seller the agreed price of the scarves (purchase price plus profit).

Is this considered Shariah-compliant?

Thanks in advance.